# Limit ONE link per post

Tags: posting

I've been browsing around Google for quite some time now, but I have yet to find a close answer.

Anyway, is there a way to limit a user to just one link (preferably outbound) per post?

Answer (score 0):

Take it as a starting point (not tested):

```
/**
 * Limit links inside the content.
 * 
 * @param (string) $content
 * @return (string) $content
 */
function wpse30754_limit_content_links( $content )
{
    // delete all <a> tags in the post
    $content = preg_replace( "/<a[^>]*><\\/a[^>]*>/", '', $content );

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse30754_limit_content_links' );
```

What's not yet implemented is preserving the first link. You'll need that on yourself.